# C++ Shortcut, Initialize array parameter in place

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets say I have a function that takes an array of floats

```
    void SetColor(float* color);
```

and I want to call that function. Typically I would do

```
    float m_Color[4] = { 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 1.0f };
    SetColor( m_Color );
```

Is there a neater way of doing this? I'm expecting something along the lines of

```
    SetColor( { 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 1.0f } )
```

if something exists.

I don't want to change the parameter type because sometimes the parameter is hard coded but other times it is set programmatically.

Comment: Is the number of elements in the array fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such things as array literals. If you can, make `SetColor()` take a `std::array<float, N>` and pass that instance:

```c++
template <unsigned N>
void SetColor(std::array<float, N> color);

SetColor(std::array<float, 4>{{ 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 1.0f }});
```

If you can't change the parameter, `std::array` has a `data()` member function that returns a pointer to its internal array:

```c++
SetColor(std::array<float, 4>{{ 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 1.0f }}.data());
```

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what I wanted. I was hoping for something cleaner, but my question was does anything neater exist.

Comment: @RussellTrahan This works too (but not on g++ for some reason): `using T = float[4]; SetColor(T{ 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 1.0f });`. Much neater.

Answer (score 3):

Using [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

```
void SetColor(std::initializer_list<float> l) {
    DoSomething(l.begin(), l.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you change the signature of `SetColor` to one of:

```
void SetColor(std::initializer_list<float> color);

void SetColor(const std::vector<float>& color);

void SetColor(const std::array<float, 4>& color);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2cb308e2eebf5af)

Comment: Not the latter if `N` needs to be deduced.